# Show categories and subcategories with 2 while statement

Tags: php, html, mysql

[image]

I have a mysql table for categories and subcategories to order in a dropdown menu list. I thought to use a while statement into while, but i get only the first main category with relative subcategories and then the loop stop after the first record.

How i want to display it:

```
-1 main cat  
   -1.1 sub-cat
   -1.2 sub-cat ...and so on

-2 main cat
   - 2.1 sub-cat
   - 2.2 sub-cat...and so on
```

this is the simple test page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
<?php

    $main_cat = "SELECT * 
                FROM category 
                WHERE cat_parent_id = :value 
                AND cat_lang = 'gb' 
                ORDER BY cat_id ASC";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($main_cat);
    $stmt->bindValue(':value', 0, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($row_main = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        extract($row_main);   
 ?>     
<li><?php echo $cat_name; ?></li>
  <li>
   <ul>
  <?php

        $sub_cat = "SELECT * 
                    FROM category 
                    WHERE cat_parent_id = ?  
                    ORDER BY cat_id ASC";
        $stmt = $con->prepare($sub_cat);
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $cat_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        while ($row_sub = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            extract($row_sub);   
 ?>   

<li><?php echo $cat_name; ?></li>
<?php   }
    } 
?>          

    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think the problem could be that you are overriding $stmt variable in a second query, but haven't tested. Try to change $stmt in a second query to something else.

Comment: Are you using **Category** table for save **Category &  subcategory**.   In your sample code you used both while statement with Category table. Please do let me know your exact problem or please provide your table structure.

Comment: **NOTE** Using `extract();` in the global scope is a real **NoNo** and should not be done, for more reasons than there is space herer to describe. Use `$row['columnName']`

Comment: Just a minor thing - your SQL statement vary slightly - one uses a bind variable name, the other a `?`, one uses `AND cat_lang = 'gb'` whilst the other doesn't.  Sometimes it's worth being consistent in how you write your code.

Comment: @RiggsFolly: why? Can you post a link for documentation? Thanks

Comment: It is very easy to overwrite an existing variable using it. For a simple example if both your tables had an `id` column (which lots do) using extract after 2 queries using `*` at which point would the `$id` contain the id from select1 and when would it contain the id from select 2. !!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that for the second nested SQL, you use the same variable name for the statement...

```
$stmt = $con->prepare($sub_cat);
```

as

```
$stmt = $con->prepare($main_cat);
```

So when the inner loop finished reading all of the records, it would go to the outer loop and also see that all of the records from `$stmt` had been read.

You would be better off using something like

```
$stmtSub = $con->prepare($sub_cat);
```

and update all of the references for the second statement.

You could also move this prepare outside of both the while loops so that it is just prepared once and then re-executed each time.

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes :

Use different name of `$stmt` for sub category like `$stmt2 or $stmt_sub.`

You should always use different variables for different prepared statements.